# How do I ip route add automatically when I connect to a L2TP VPN

Tags: networking, ip, vpn

I am connecting to a L2TP VPN. When I connect to that VPN I need to run the following command to get it to work:

```
sudo ip route add {ip}/24 dev ppp0
```

How do I run this command automatically when I connect to a VPN or set that route in the GUI? I am using Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Comment: Are you using network manager to manage your VPN?

Comment: @Stewart yes i am using network manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I added the route to the connection using nmcli

```
nmcli con modify "<connection name>" +ipv4.routes "<ip>/24"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be dependant on the VPN you are using. as @roaima said, if it is openvpn, you can add it to the client config as `route [ip] 255.255.255.0 [gateway]`.
Where "ip" is actually the subnet you want to route, and gateway is the gateway of your vpn network interface.

For things like wireguard, here is a reddit discussion on the subject:

https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/cwz0fe/route_traffic_for_wireguard_subnet_through/

for other vpns (expressvpn, etc), it might not be possible.

Comment: I am using L2TP, it's a work VPN

Comment: @Magnus please add that to your question. It's an important detail